# i've just finished this script it connects to the main script but the doesnt print a csv

Tags: python, csv, import

i've just finished this script it connects to the main script and the website runs but it doesnt print a csv like i want it to have i done something wrong in my script when i try the /dan route it says it cant find the csv

```
import psutil
import sys
import os
import inspect
import socket
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from time import gmtime, strftime
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, app, request, redirect, 
url_for, send_file, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from time import sleep
import requests
import data
import tank
import csv
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__')) 

def funcScript():

    from data import tankOBJ as tank
    with open(os.path.join('F:\csvtester', '\motherwell.csv'),'w',newline='') as 
    output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        writer.writerow(tank)


return 'Hello World!'
```

here is the function above to output the csv and below is the output for the webapp

```
@app.route('/dan')
def downloadDocument():
try:
    return csvmotherwell.funcScript()
except Exception as error:
    return event.Error(str(inspect.stack()[1][3]), str(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), str(type(error)), str(error))
```

Comment: that is my mistake it is indented in the program just a mistake on my part while writing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.path.join('F:\csvtester', '\motherwell.csv')
```

doesn't work. The result is `'F:\motherwell.csv'`

you probably want

```
os.path.join(r'F:\csvtester', 'motherwell.csv')
```

which yields:

```
F:\csvtester\motherwell.csv
```

(note the raw prefix to avoid characters being interpreted by backslashes)